# How to do a binding in Xaml?

Tags: xml, linq, xaml, data-binding

I have a Linq query below with 'product' containing sub-elements 'Name' and 'Price' in an XML file.

```
var queryAllProducts = from product in products 
select new { 
    Product = product 
,   PriceEuro = UsdToEuro(product.PriceUsd) 
};
```

In my xaml file, I can bind a Textblock to PriceEuro with

```
<TextBlock Text= "{Binding PriceEuro}" />
```

How do I bind a TextBlock to 'Name'? `Text = "{Binding Product.Name}"` didn't work for me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Text="{Binding Path=Product.Name}"
```

Use Path.

Comment: I tried Path, but it didn't work for me. If I just use "{Binding Product}" then it shows the whole node (including Name and Price). The same result if I use "Binding Path=Food}".Thanks.

Comment: Clarification: "Binding Product" works the same as "Binding Path=Product" but "Binding Product.Name" or "Binding Path=Product.Name" doesn't work.